# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tree_dict' in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, sql, database, dictionary, pysimplegui

Below is PySimpleGUI code to create a multilanguage dictionary where I can add entries for each word in different languages, and also have the possibility to search by language. Unfortunately, I got the following error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tree_dict'

How can I fix this?

```py
import sqlite3
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Create connection to SQLite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('Data_Enteries.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table if it doesn't exist
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dictionary
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              English TEXT,
              French TEXT,
              Spanish TEXT,
              Chinese TEXT,
              Swedish TEXT,
              Turkish TEXT)''')
conn.commit()

# Create PySimpleGUI layout
layout = [[sg.Text('Enter word to search: '), sg.InputText(key='search'), 
           sg.Button('Search')],
          [sg.Tree(data=[], headings=['English', 'French', 'Spanish', 'Chinese', 'Swedish', 
            'Turkish'], key='treeview', col_widths=[20]*6)]]

# Create PySimpleGUI window
window = sg.Window('Multilanguage Dictionary', layout)

# Function to retrieve data from database
def search_database(word):
    # Execute SELECT query
    c.execute('''SELECT * FROM dictionary
                 WHERE English = ? OR
                       French = ? OR
                       Spanish = ? OR
                       Chinese = ? OR
                       Swedish = ? OR
                       Turkish = ?''', (word, word, word, word, word, word))
    results = c.fetchall()
    # Convert results to PySimpleGUI treeview data format
    data = []
    for row in results:
        data.append([row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]])
    return data

# Loop to handle PySimpleGUI events
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Search':
        search_word = values['search']
        tree_data = search_database(search_word)
        window['treeview'].update(values=tree_data)

# Close PySimpleGUI window and SQLite database connection
conn.close()
window.close()
```

Traceback:

```
C:\UsersUserName\Desktop>MultiLangPSG.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\UsersUserName\Desktop\MultiLangPSG.py", line 47, in <module>
    event, values = window.read()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\UsersUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10075, in read
    results = self._read(timeout=timeout, timeout_key=timeout_key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\UsersUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 10146, in _read
    self._Show()
  File "C:\UsersUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 9886, in _Show
    StartupTK(self)
  File "C:\UsersUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 16866, in StartupTK
    _convert_window_to_tk(window)
  File "C:\UsersUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 16753, in _convert_window_to_tk
    PackFormIntoFrame(window, master, window)
  File "C:\UsersUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PySimpleGUI\PySimpleGUI.py", line 16402, in PackFormIntoFrame
    for key, node in element.TreeData.tree_dict.items():
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tree_dict'
```

Comment: I suggest you post a [mre] and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @khelwood, Thanks for prompt feedback, an example is shared in my above question.

Comment: @khelwood, anything to add from my side? Thx

Comment: @PyiPath2022 can you provide the traceback as requested by khelwood? We kinda need it... it doesn't' appear you actually have something calling `tree_dict` in the code snippet, so it might be something to do with `PySimpleGUI`. Eitherways, we need the traceback, the full thing.

Comment: @AnonyMous .Updated above please check

Comment: @PyiPath2022 ok... sorry to bother you again, but can you edit that but surround the traceback with triple backquotes (like ` character)? That being said, I think the issue is with the module itself, not with your code.  Maybe try reinstalling the module.

Comment: @AnonyMous, no issue. Done

Comment: @PyiPath2022 Ok so I think the issue might be related to your input (maybe line 26? or 20?) or it would otherwise be the module's fault. I'm not going to pretend I know this module, but maybe your layout is incorrect?

Comment: layout should be OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Argument `data` in `sg.Tree`
>
> The data represented using a PySimpleGUI provided TreeData class
>
> type data: (TreeData)

Demo Code

```py
treedata = sg.TreeData()
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Enter word to search: '),
     sg.InputText(key='search'),
     sg.Button('Search')],
    [sg.Tree(data=treedata, headings=['English', 'French', 'Spanish', 'Chinese', 'Swedish','Turkish'], key='treeview', col_widths=[20]*6)],
]
```

Comment: Excellent!!! How to add "Add New" "Delete" and "update" ?

Comment: Seems the layout is OK , but not possible to retrieve data from database using search field

Comment: Again, the type for the option `values` of method `update` is `sg.TreeData`, not a list. Check `tree_data = search_database(search_word)`, the function `search_database` return a list.  There's no method provided to Inset/Delete/Update for items in the `Tree`, you need to check the structure of `sg.TreeData` for your requirements, or more tkinter knowledge to know how they work.